# Custom command requires calling CMake three times to have desired output

Tags: android, c++, cmake, cross-compiling, clion

My project is fairly simple. I have an app that includes a library written based on integration platfrom so it looks something like this:

```
My app

  ----> Extension

        ----> Main library
```

The app is cross-compiled to Android. All of them are based on CMake. I'm using CLion as an IDE. I've added a profile with custom toolchain required to build for Android (that is clang, clang++ for apropiate platform, cmake from Android SDK and make from Android NDK r20b). Problem is I have to call CMake 3 times (reload it in CLion) before it generates all of the files needed. Whole file is listed below.

On the first run it ignores the fact it is build for android (doesn't go into if (ANDROID) ) and copies the prebuilt sub-executable for linux (default)

On the second run it ignores the needed *android.toolchain.cmake* and when build on this stage it fails to add android headers to search path BUT chooses correct prebuilt sub-executable

On the the third run it uses the *android.toolchain.cmake* file AND chooses correct sub-executable.

After that I can hit build and everything compiles correctly.

The CMake I have:

```
add_executable(androidApp main.cpp)

target_include_directories(androidApp
        PUBLIC
        ../submodules/exten/src/libraries/main_lib/lib/include
        ../submodules/exten/src/libraries/main_lib/sdk/rlogging/include) //Headers from main library

target_link_libraries(androidApp
        PRIVATE
        exten) //Extension

install(TARGETS androidApp DESTINATION ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)
install(FILES ../submodules/exten/src/libraries/main_lib/integration_app/resources/someFile.zip DESTINATION ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)
install(FILES ../resources/someFile2.zip DESTINATION ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/bin/resources)

file(MAKE_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/bin/bootsafe)
file(WRITE ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/bin/bootsafe/dummy "") //Required dir

add_custom_command(TARGET dongleApp POST_BUILD
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/ndk/android-ndk-r20b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/arm-linux-androideabi/bin/strip --strip-debug dongleApp
        WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}
        COMMENT "Stripping debug symbols")

if (ANDROID)
    target_link_libraries(androidApp
            PRIVATE
            log)
endif (ANDROID) //Linking android lib
```

On different CMake (on the main library level) here's how the choosing on correct prebuilt is written

```
if(NOT ANDROID)
    set(PREBUILD_NAME "linux")
else()
    if(ANDROID_ABI STREQUAL "x86_64")
        set(PREBUILD_NAME "android-x86")
    else()
        set(PREBUILD_NAME "android-arm")
    endif()
endif()
```

The command that is used to generate makefiles:

```
/home/gravlok/companyName/app_v2/sdk/cmake/3.10.2.4988404/bin/cmake 
-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug
-DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=/home/gravlok/companyName/app_v2/ndk/android-ndk-r20b/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/make
-DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=/home/gravlok/companyName/app_v2/ndk/android-ndk-r20b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/armv7a-linux-androideabi28-clang
-DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/home/gravlok/companyName/app_v2/ndk/android-ndk-r20b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/armv7a-linux-androideabi28-clang++
-DANDROID=ON
-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/home/gravlok/companyName/app_v2/ndk/android-ndk-r20b/build/cmake/android.toolchain.cmake -DANDROID_PLATFORM=android-28
-G "CodeBlocks - Unix Makefiles"
/home/gravlok/companyName/app_v2
```

Why do I need to run it 3 times in order to configure correctly?